# Python Loop using 2 lists

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to add a second variable to a loop statment but failing badly. Cannot work out how to loop using 2 lists.

The below code works for iterating through the pages in the API. So for the exchange Binance I get 8 pages of data.

I have another list called id_list which has a list of >100 exchange that I also want to added to the loop.

I want the code to call the api for binance and paginate through 8 pages, then move on the next exchange and paginate through and append.

Here is what I have so far.

```
appended_data = []


for i in range(1,10):
    data =  cg.get_exchanges_tickers_by_id('binance', page = str(i))
    appended_data.append(data)
    
appended_data = pd.json_normalize(appended_data, record_path=['tickers'], meta=['name'])  
appended_data.to_csv('help.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nested loops:

```
for exchange in id_list:
    for i in range(1, 10):
        data =  cg.get_exchanges_tickers_by_id(exchange, page = str(i))
        appended_data.append(data)
```